# Manually refreshing token - Google API

Tags: php, google-api, token, access-token, google-api-php-client

I'm using the Google API to connect to AdSence, and I need my script to run on the background - meaning without user interfering.

I'm writing my code in PHP. This is how I've created my token:

```
$token = array(
    'access_token' => 'XXXX',
    'refresh_token' => 'XXXX',
    'expires_in' => 3600,
    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    "created" => 1461760640
    );
$json_token = json_encode($token);
$client->setAccessToken($json_token);
```

Now, the Token's life-time is one hour.
I need to refresh the token in the script - and insert the new tokens to the "$token" variable - so my script could run alone.

I'm using two Google's libraries:

1. google-api-php-client-1-master
2. googleads-adsense-examples-master

Does anyone know how to manually refresh the token?
Thank you!

Comment: $client->refreshToken($google_token->refresh_token);  then $client->getAccessToken() I think

Comment: @DaImTo  what is $google_token variable? Thanks!

Comment: probably your $token[refresh_token] my PHP is a little rusty sorry.

Comment: @DaImTo  Thank you :) each token has a one hour life-time, I'll update you later :)

Comment: There is something in the client library that lets you refresh it if its expired.   If you get it to work remember to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DalmTo, I've managed manually refreshing the token.

This is my new code:

```
$refrehToken='XXXX';
$client->refreshToken($refrehToken);
$tempToken=$client->getAccessToken();
$tempToken=json_decode($tempToken, true);

$token = array(
        'access_token' => $tempToken["access_token"],
        'refresh_token' => $refrehToken,
        'expires_in' => 3600,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        "created" => 1461760640
);
$json_token = json_encode($token);
$client->setAccessToken($json_token);
```